# CiviCRM is exporting disabled groups, how can I specify that I want enabled groups only?

Tags: groups, export

I have done several exports with "Groups" as one of the fields. In each case, it exports both enabled and disabled groups. Is there any way to specify that I would like to see enabled groups only?